# Cannot insert Nextval for SEQ in db2 using java

Tags: java, db2, nextval

I am trying to insert data into a db2 table using nextval for seq but I am getting the following errors in the log:

```
PreparedStatementnextval for maximo.REGION_SHEET_2GIDSEQ

ERROR: [jcc][1091][10404][3.63.123] Invalid data conversion: Parameter instance nextval for maximo.REGION_SHEET_2GIDSEQ is invalid for the requested conversion. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: [jcc][1091][10404][3.63.123] Invalid data conversion: Parameter instance nextval for maximo.REGION_SHEET_2GIDSEQ is invalid for the requested conversion. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815

        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:679)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:60)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.a(fd.java:103)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hc.a(hc.java:744)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hc.a(hc.java:664)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hc.a(hc.java:1336)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hc.a(hc.java:1306)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.io.a(io.java:2370)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.io.Bc(io.java:5586)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.io.l(io.java:2753)
```

I am passing the following string a variable an then calling it in a different class preparedstatement.

`String Region_Sheet_2gid = "nextval for maximo.REGION_SHEET_2GIDSEQ";`

Assigning above value to `REGION_SHEET_2GID` in below insert statement

```
 public String getInsertStatement() {
    return "insert into maximo." +tablename+ " (SITECODE,BSCNAME,CITYNAME,REGION,VENDOR,TYPE"
        + ",NOOFCELLS,RBU,LATITUTE,LONGITUDE,LAC,SITENAME,ISACTIVE,PRIORITY,STATUS_2G_3G,REGION_SHEET_2GID,MORAN_SITES,DEODAR_SHARED,SITEPOWERPROFILETYPE,SITETYPE,OMC)"
        + " values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
  }
```

PrepareStatement :
 `ps.setString(16, this.getREGION_SHEET_2GID());`

SettersGetter:

```
public String getREGION_SHEET_2GID() 

{
    return REGION_SHEET_2GID;
}
```

```
public void setREGION_SHEET_2GID(String rEGION_SHEET_2GID) {
    REGION_SHEET_2GID = rEGION_SHEET_2GID;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the data type of the *target column* in the Db2-table? If you are converting to a string , convert it back to the correct data type before binding the parameter.

Comment: The target column is BigInt but I am passing it as a String because I want it to be printed as it is "nextval for maximo.REGION_SHEET_2GIDSEQ "

When inserting data manually in the same table the nextval is passed as string where as its column is BigInt (auto incremented primary key)

Comment: You cannot bind the expression `nextval for maximo.REGION_SHEET_2GIDSEQ` as a parameter; it has to be embedded as part of the statement text.